# Add script to clear Chrome upon logoff

Tags: beginner, batch, google-chrome

This program automatically makes folders to add scripts to be ran once a computer is logged off a user. It checks to make sure it is not overwriting any previous scripts (windows).

```
:: Author: Brandon Finley
:: Date: 4/20/2017
:: Purpose: This program automatically makes folders to add scripts to be ran once a computer is logged off a user. It checks to make sure it is not overwriting any previous scripts
:: that may have already been created, and then adds the ChromeClear to the list. THIS PROGRAM IS A TOTAL NUKE TO THE CHROME BROWSER; IT WILL DELETE EVERYTHING!


:: If there are no previous scripts added, it needs to create the file locations to use
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User MD C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User
IF NOT EXIST  C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts MD C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts
IF NOT EXIST C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logoff MD C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logoff

:: Writes the new .bat file to clear the browsers
ECHO SET ChromeDir=C:\Users\%%USERNAME%%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data> C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logoff\ChromeClear.bat
ECHO DEL /q /s /f "%%ChromeDir%%">> C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logoff\ChromeClear.bat
ECHO RD /s /q "%%ChromeDir%%">> C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logoff\ChromeClear.bat

:: If there are no previous scripts.ini initialized it makes the begining of the new file (creates a new scripts.ini if not already there).
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\scripts.ini" @echo:>>C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\scripts.ini
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%k in ('find /c "Logoff" "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\scripts.ini"') do set theLogoff=%%k
IF /I %theLogoff%==0 @echo [Logoff]>> C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\scripts.ini

:: Writes to the scripts.ini file, and tries to continue the script counter if previous scripts are already added (which is why it doesn't just simply start at 0, but instead counts the scripts).
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%f in ('find /c "CmdLine" "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\scripts.ini"') do set isComplete=%%f
ECHO %isComplete%CmdLine=ChromeClear.bat>> C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\scripts.ini
ECHO %isComplete%Parameters=>> C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\scripts.ini

:: Deletes the .bat file at it's location.
DEL "%~f0"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Code Review!  Please review [How do I ask a good Question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Specifically, it is best to explain what the code does.  This is especially true in the title. It looks like you did this in the comments, but it would be best to transfer that to prose a the beginning on the post.

Comment: Seems like extraneous information to just copy and paste what the comments say. Please refer to the comments provided in the script as to what it does.

Comment: Yes but, note that you are trying to attract peoples attention to your post so that you can get their feedback.  The easier you make it for them to see if they are going to be productive in providing feedback, the more likely you will get that feedback.  If they have to spend much time determining if they can help they may just move on.

Comment: I guess if I don't then I just get people criticizing on the format of the question rather than the question itself. Thanks for the useful insight to this website.

Comment: @StephenRauch I really don't understand what should be wrong with this question? It's just an ordinary batch file with comments and a brief description. I find this question is just as it should be.

Comment: @t3chb0t, There is nothing terribly wrong with the question. I came to the post from *First Posts* so felt some responsibility to orient the OP. So, I suggested he turn it into a question instead of a code dump. Before the edit, there was no prose. I was the third person to see the post, and one of the first two had already down voted it. I assumed because there was no introduction or other description. I personally up-voted the question after the edit, although I think it could still be a better question with some prose describing *how* and *why*, instead of just the current *what*. Cheers.

Comment: @StephenRauch oh, I see. I didn't check the edit history but I would have done the same if I was here before you ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t
Even after the post is fixed, you have yet to criticize (negatively or positively) the actual content of the post. You are a very poor representation of this website.

Comment: @Brandon I have no idea what you are talking about.